# Magento 2.1 , Repeated texarea and select element not clickable

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7

I have override the `Magento_Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml` template.**Textarea** and **Select html element** **not click able** inside this **template**. How to solve it?

```
<?php
$stores = $block->getStoresSortedBySortOrder();

//For, display custom field design, based on specific attribute code
$customAttributeCode = $block->getAttrCode();
?>
<fieldset class="admin__fieldset fieldset">
    <legend class="legend">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Manage Options (Values of Your Attribute)')) ?></span>
    </legend><br />
    <div class="admin__control-table-wrapper" id="manage-options-panel" data-index="attribute_options_select_container">
        <table class="admin__control-table" data-index="attribute_options_select">
            <thead>
                <tr id="attribute-options-table">
                <th class="col-draggable"></th>
                <th class="col-default control-table-actions-th">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Is Default')) ?></span>
                </th>
                <?php foreach ($stores as $_store): ?>
                    <th<?php if ($_store->getId() == \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID): ?> class="_required"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_store->getName())) ?></span>
                    </th>
                    <?php if ($customAttributeCode) { ?>
                        <th>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Description')) ?></span> 
                        </th>
                    <?php } ?>


                    <?php
                endforeach;
                ?>
                <?php if ($customAttributeCode) { ?>
                    <th>
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Image Url')) ?></span> 
                    </th>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php
                $storetotal = count($stores) + 9;
                ?>
                <th class="col-delete">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-role="options-container" class="ignore-validate"></tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <th colspan="<?= (int) $storetotal ?>" class="validation">
                    <input type="hidden" class="required-dropdown-attribute-entry" name="dropdown_attribute_validation"/>
                    <input type="hidden" class="required-dropdown-attribute-unique" name="dropdown_attribute_validation_unique"/>
                </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th colspan="<?= (int) $storetotal ?>" class="col-actions-add">
                    <?php if (!$block->getReadOnly() && !$block->canManageOptionDefaultOnly()): ?>
                    <button id="add_new_option_button" data-action="add_new_row"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Option')) ?>"
                            type="button" class="action- scalable add">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Option')) ?></span>
                    </button>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" id="option-count-check" value="" />
    </div>
    <script id="row-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
        <tr>
        <td class="col-draggable">

                <textarea name="option[description][<%- data.id %>][<?= (int) $_store->getId() ?>]" rows='2' cols='25' class="admin__control-textarea" ><%- data.description<?= /* @noEscape */ (int) $_store->getId() ?> %></textarea>
                <select>
                <option value="wipro">wipro</option>
                <option value="zoho">zoho</option>
                <option value="ox">ox</option>
                </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
    </script>
    <?php
    $values = [];
    foreach ($block->getOptionValues() as $value) {
        $value = $value->getData();
        $values[] = is_array($value) ? array_map("htmlspecialchars_decode", $value) : $value;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
        "*":{
        "Magento_Catalog/js/options": {
        "attributesData": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($values, JSON_HEX_QUOT) ?>,
        "isSortable":  <?= (int) (!$block->getReadOnly() && !$block->canManageOptionDefaultOnly()) ?>,
        "isReadOnly": <?= (int) $block->getReadOnly() ?>
        },
        "Magento_Catalog/catalog/product/attribute/unique-validate": {
        "element": "required-dropdown-attribute-unique",
        "message": "<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("The value of Admin must be unique.")) ?>"
        }
        }
        }
    </script>
</fieldset>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ4oR.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because your options doesn’t have *values*.

```
 <select>
  <option value=“wipro”>Wipro</option>
  <option value=“zoho”>Zoho</option>
  <option value=“ox”>OX</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But after give values still have same issue and textarea  also not clickable....

Comment: Can u give us a screenshot of your form and the compiled code from the inspecter?

Comment: i have added my form image and correct coding